# Python - Remove duplicate key from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries in Python:

```
[{u'value': u'firstname', u'key': u'Coach'}, 
 {u'value': u'lastname', u'key': u'Coach'}, 
 {u'value': u'age', u'key': u'Coach'}, 
 {u'value': u'firstname', u'key': u'Player'}, 
 {u'value': u'league', u'key': u'Player'}]
```

How can I remove duplicate **key** from a list of dictionaries and merge their values into a list as shown below:

```
l = [('Coach', ['firstname', 'lastname', 'age']), 
     ('Player', ['firstname', 'league'])]
```

Iterate over list items

```
for k, v in l:
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) as value type in order to collect values:

```
In [5]: from collections import defaultdict

In [6]: data = [{u'value': u'firstname', u'key': u'Coach'}, 
 {u'value': u'lastname', u'key': u'Coach'}, 
 {u'value': u'age', u'key': u'Coach'}, 
 {u'value': u'firstname', u'key': u'Player'}, 
 {u'value': u'league', u'key': u'Player'}]

In [7]: l = defaultdict(list)

In [8]: for row in data:
   ...:     l[row['key']].append(row['value'])
   ...:     

In [9]: l
Out[9]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'Coach': ['firstname', 'lastname', 'age'],
             'Player': ['firstname', 'league']})
```

And then you could easily convert the dictionary into a list of tuples using [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method:

```
In [10]: list(l.items())
Out[10]: 
[('Coach', ['firstname', 'lastname', 'age']),
 ('Player', ['firstname', 'league'])]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[(k, [x['value'] for x in v]) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['key']), lambda d: d['key'])]
```

`groupby` is in the standard module `itertools`.

**EDIT:**
Thank @soon for pointing out that `itertools.groupby` requires input sequence being consecutive, thus need to sort beforehand.

Comment: `groupby` groups consecutive elements only

Comment: [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) could also be useful.